# Adding csv tables to github using README.rst

Tags: github, restructuredtext

So github claims to support reStructured text for the README.md file, and that's great, because I have a bill of materials in a .csv file I would like to add via the following to my README.rst:

```
.. csv-table::
    :widths: 25 25 25 25
    :file: bom.csv
```

However, when I view the page on [my repository](https://github.com/edmundsj/AD7766DevBoard), all I see is the heading (as expected), and some text, but not the table. Further, I don't know where to find any output files from github's internal parsing engine to help me figure out what the problem is. This works just fine when building with sphinx on my local machine (the table is embedded as expected). What is the potential issue here, and how do I view github's internal outputs that would give me a clue as to what is going wrong?

Comment: GitHub has limited support for rendering reStructuredText. You should use markdown if your sole purpose is to render the file on GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSV tables are a feature of the Sphinx-flavoured rST, not the plain Docutils rST. GitHub is using plain. You have to use either simple or grid tables on GH, see https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#tables

Comment: Thanks! Too bad they don't support reST, but I get it. Adds overhead and complexity.